# Conditional Required Field in SharePoint List (Exact text match)

Tags: validation-list-items, formula

I need to write a rule to conditionally require data in a field based on the values in two other columns:

**Status** Column: Values include "Active" or "Inactive"

**Type** Column: Values include "Full Time","Part Time","Temporary"

I need a third column, **Name** to be required when **Status**="Active" AND **Type**="Full Time" OR "Part Time"

My current attempt is this:
   `=IF([@[Status]]="Active",AND([@[Type]]="Full Time",OR[@[Resource Type]]="Part Time",TRUE,FALSE)TRUE)`

This does not work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean (Status="Active" AND Type="Full Time") OR "Part Time", or do you mean: Status="Active" AND (Type="Full Time" OR "Part Time")

Comment: If Type column includes either Full time or Part time. Why would you want to add it in formula. Select anyone as default choice. And use formula based on Status column only. Also you have used Type as well as Resource Type in your formula. What does this Resource Type column?

Comment: @Mike2500 I mean the second statement.

Comment: @GaneshSanap For Type, there is actually a third value so I need to exclude that one. I've edited the original question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're referring to different fields, the validation logic will go in the list settings --> validation settings, not the validation settings for the individual column.

```
=NOT(AND(AND(Status="Active",OR([Job Type]="Full Time",[Job Type]="Part Time")),[Employee Name]=""))
```